# Showing customer spinner for 5 seconds after which show content

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am developing a react-native project. I have a spinner as a custom component:

```
const MySpinner = ({hide = false}) => {
   ...
   if (hide) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Animated.View>
          <MyIcon />
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see above, there is a `hide` property which decides whether I show `MySpinner` or not in parent component.

In `MyScreen`, I would like to show `MySpinner` for 5 seconds, after which show the actual content (No networking callback involved). I try to use `setTimeOut` function to achieve it.

This is what I tried:

```
const MyScreen = () {
   ...

   return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {setTimeout(() => { <MySpinner hide={true}/>}, 3000)}
        <ActualContent />
     </View>
   )

}
```

At runtime, I got error  `Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.`

Also, the above code doesn't show actual content after `MySpinner` disappear.

So, how can I achieve what I need? That's showing MySpinner at first for 5 seconds after that show the actual content.

Comment: Add `showSpinner` state to the `MyScreen` component and toggle it with `useEffect` in which you can `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in multiple ways, here is a simple example to help you get started.

Code Sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-chebyshev-io6pd?file=/src/App.js

[UPDATED ANSWER]

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSpinner(false);
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  const component = spinner ? (
    <span>Loading...</span>
  ) : (
    <h1>Component Ready</h1>
  );

  return <div className="App">{component}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but your code doesn't meet the requirement, it shows the spinner after 5 seconds & always show there after that, but the requirement of the question is to show it at the beginning and after 5 seconds spinner should be disappeared then the content shows.

Comment: Check the answer now, its updated. its just a flip in the code

Comment: @Leem.fin , Did you get your issue fixed ? Did the answer work ?